# Intellij Idea shows directory twice

Tags: intellij-idea

Here is a picture that describes the problem,

[image]

As you can see the `views` folder is in a strange position, but if I created another directory with another name the folder get aligned correctly inside the project structure tree.

I also tried creating the folder outside of Intellij Idea and I got the same results.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder what else to share? I'm just right clicking and choosing to create a new directory but I get two folders instead of one in the files viewer

Comment: Zip and share the project directory.

Comment: Looks like intellij thinks that the view folder is a module, maybe a weird import? You could try with right click in the view folder and click in the "delete module" option.